# ORA-01008: not all variables bound. I keep getting this error altough my query and code is fine

Tags: c#, oracle11g

Table creation code for Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE  "STUDENTS" 
(
    "S_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FULL_NAME" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "CONTACT_NO" VARCHAR2(25), 
    "GENDER" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "STATUS" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "ADMISSION_DATE" DATE, 
    "ADMISSION_NO" NUMBER, 
    "FATHER_NAME" VARCHAR2(25), 
    "MOTHER_NAME" VARCHAR2(25), 
    "DATE_OF_BIRTH" DATE, 
    "NATIONALITY" VARCHAR2(15), 
    "RELIGION" VARCHAR2(15), 
    "CLASS_NO" VARCHAR2(5), 
    "SECTION_NAME" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "S_ROLL_NO" VARCHAR2(15), 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GUARDIAN_FULL_NAME" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GUARDIAN_CONTACT_NO" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GUARDIAN_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PRE_SCHOOL" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "PRIMARY" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "MIDDLE" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "MIDDLE_YEAROFPASS" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "MIDDLE_INSTITUTION" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "HIGH_SCHOOL_SSC" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "SSC_YEAROFPASS" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "SSC_INSTITUTION" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "HIGHER_SECONDARY_HSSC" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "HSSC_YEAROFPASS" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "HSSC_INSTITUTION" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "IMAGE" BLOB, 

     CONSTRAINT "STUDENTS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("S_ID", "USERNAME") ENABLE
 );

ALTER TABLE "STUDENTS" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT "STUDENTS_SECTION_NAME_FK" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_NAME")
    REFERENCES  "SECTIONS" ("SECTION_NAME") ENABLE;
```

Image conversion

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(imgpath, FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file);
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(imgpath);
byte[] imgData = br.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
```

Student registration...

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

Oracle query to insert into students table

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into HRM.students values(:s_id, :username, 
:full_name, :email, :contact_no, :gender, :status" +
", :admission_date, :admission_no, :father_name, :mother_name, 
:date_of_birth, :nationality, :religion, :class_no, :section_name" +
", :s_roll_no, :password, :guardian_full_name, :guardian_contact_no, 
:guardian_address, :pre_school, :primary_school, :middle" +
", :middle_yearofpass, :middle_institution, :high_school_ssc, 
:ssc_yearofpass, :ssc_institution, :higher_secondary_hssc" +
", :hssc_yearofpass, :hssc_institution, :image)";

string DOB = usr_DOB.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Adding parameters, all the specified table parameters are added with the replacing values, can't find out which parameter is causing the error

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("s_id", GenerateNewID());
```

The `GenerateNewID()` method just simply fetches a counter for previous admissions and adds 1 and returns for the newID

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("username", usr_name.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("full_name", usr_fullname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("email", usr_email.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("contact_no", usr_contactNo.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("gender", genderVal);
cmd.Parameters.Add("status", StatusVal);
```

Status (enabled / false), gender and some other variables are evaluated to 0 or 1 based on binary conditions where only two options were available.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("admission_date", dated);
cmd.Parameters.Add("admission_no", GenerateNewID());
cmd.Parameters.Add("father_name", usr_fathername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("mother_name", usr_mothername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("date_of_birth", DOB);
cmd.Parameters.Add("nationality", usr_nationality.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("religion", usr_religion.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("class_no", usr_Class.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("section_name", usr_assignedSection.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("s_roll_no", GenerateNewID());
cmd.Parameters.Add("password", password);
cmd.Parameters.Add("guardian_full_name", usr_GuardianName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("guardian_contact_no", usr_GuardianContactNo.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("guardian_address", usr_GuardianFullAddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("pre_school", preVal);
cmd.Parameters.Add("primary_school", primaryVal);
cmd.Parameters.Add("middle", midVal);
cmd.Parameters.Add("middle_yearofpass", usr_middle_yearOfPass.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("middle_institution", usr_middle_insititution.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("high_school_ssc", secondaryVal);
cmd.Parameters.Add("ssc_yearofpass", usr_ssc_yearOfPass.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("ssc_institution", usr_secondary_insititution.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("higher_secondary_hssc", higherSecondaryVal);
cmd.Parameters.Add("hssc_yearofpass", usr_hssc_yearOfPass.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("hssc_institution",         
usr_HighSecondary_institution.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("image", (Object)imgData);

con.Open();
```

Execution

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: I don't think you want to bind the PK as a parameter. I'm assuming you're using a sequence and trigger to autoincrement the value since this is Oracle. So in the first part of your query `"insert into HRM.students values(:s_id,` you should change it to `"insert into HRM.students values(SEQUENCE_NAME.nextval,` and then remove this: `cmd.Parameters.Add("s_id", GenerateNewID());`

Comment: I've connected Oracle databse using Oracle Client in viusal studio and i'm trying to register a student but when i execute the specified querie the it complains that not all the specified parameters are bound, but all the parameters are indeed bound and are being replaced by their values while adding the parameters..

The problem is i can't identify exactly which parameter is causing this issue...

Comment: I'm still getting the same error
    "insert into HRM.students values(SEQUENCE_NAME.nextval,
it doesn't works the error says not all variables are bound but all of 'em are bounded to their specific datatype value

Comment: I added an answer with more detail and different things you should try.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. Like I mentioned in the comment, you don't bind IDs/PKs in an insert statement like that. In the insert instead of `:s_id` use `SEQUENCE_NAME.nextval` though you'll want to replace `SEQUENCE_NAME` with the name of the sequence used to increment the PK value. Since you're executing raw `SQL` instead of using something like `Entity Framework` you might have to explicitly reference the sequence. Alternatively, you could try just excluding the `ID` altogether. I'm not 100% sure so you'll have to test this, but Oracle might do the autoincrementing work for you if you're not referencing it (which in that case it becomes purely preference; personally I like having it explicitly added to the command).
2. When you're binding parameters with `cmd.Parameters.Add("hssc_yearofpass", usr_hssc_yearOfPass.Text);` you need to include `:` in the first parameter (the name of the parameter). So you should have `cmd.Parameters.Add(":hssc_yearofpass", usr_hssc_yearOfPass.Text);` and do this for all parameters.
3. It looks like all the parameters for the table are present. Just double check the spelling in addition to my 2nd point.